# php if else alternate syntax

Tags: php

Is it possible to write the if syntax somewhere close to this:

```
if (function($value)) else {echo "Error Message";}
```

If function($value), nothing needs to happen. The function returns true, but if not, I need the Error Message and I cant put that Inside the function.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this by inserting an empty statement:

```
if (function($value)) ; else {echo "Error Message";}
```

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to include a case at all if nothing needs to happen.  Thus, what you are looking for is:

```
if (!function($value)) {
    echo "Error Message";
}
```

Comment: I think I got too caught up in the single line syntax. +1 for a nice simple answer.

Comment: You can still write this on a single line, as `if (!function($value)) echo "Error Message";`, or similarly `if (!function($value)) { echo "Error Message"; }`.

Comment: Yes lol, I just didn't think of the simplest answer of using `!` in the check :)

Comment: @Fluffeh you can still do what you oroginally wanted, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is a better approach:

```
if (!function($value)){echo "Error Message";}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!function($value)) {
    echo "Error Message";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary to do this:

```
echo (function($value)? "" : "Error Message";
```

Comment: +1 This is a definite candidate for Ternary over normal IF ELSE

Answer (score 0):

```
return (function($value)? true : "Error Message");
```

returns true on valid else will return a string, which can be echoed outside.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way:

```
if (function($value)==0)
{
echo "Error Message";
}else{

//Execution code
}
```